# Error when using BreezeJS with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, breeze

Using BreezeJS with AngularJS gives errors. For example when using 'filter' in an ng-repeat the console reports: running out of stack space.

Steps to reproduce

1. Take the Todo-Angular BreezeJS sample & open in VS 2012.
2. In index.html add right before the `<ul>`

```
    <div>
    <input ng-model="query" type="search" placeholder="search" />
    </div>
```

1. Add the following code to the data-ng-repeat on the li element

```
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query">
```

The filter:query should filter the list based upon the text in the input
but it doesn't. 
In IE 10 the console reports "running out of stack space".
In Chrome the console reports"Range Error":

```
(anonymous function) angular.js:5582
(anonymous function) angular.js:4679
Scope.$digest angular.js:7739
Scope.$apply angular.js:7926
listener angular.js:11228
v.event.dispatch jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
o.handle.u
```

When you use angular.copy(src, dest); where src is created by BreezeJS I see 
another stack_overflow error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That won't work because you're asking Angular to match the search text to **every property of the TodoItem**.

A Breeze entity's properties include the `entityAspect` which has a property called `entity` that points back to the `TodoItem` instance ... and around you go until the stack overflows (pun intended).

You need to use a filter **function** that does specific comparisons. Try this:

In ***Index.html***

```
<div>
  <input data-ng-model="searchText" type="Search" placeholder="search" />
</div>
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in items | filter:itemFilter">
    ... etc. ...
```

In ***controller.js***

```
$scope.searchText = "";

// Beware: this is called a lot!
$scope.itemFilter = function (todoItem) {
    var searchText = $scope.searchText;
    // if there is search text, look for it in the description; else return true
    return searchText ?
        -1 != todoItem.Description.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) :
        true;
};
```

Works like a charm on my machine :)

p.s.: your mishap with `angular.copy()` has the same cause ... it does a depth copy of every property and entities tend to have circular references.

Comment: Nice answer! Love to see a custom breeze filter that excludes entityAspect properties, etc. :)

Comment: Another option for this can be found at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277725/dynamic-select-element-filtering-in-angular/18278363?noredirect=1#comment26814224_18278363 - You can pass a JSON object into the filter parameter to remove the need to create a custom function on the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i implemented a custom filter, that excludes navigation properties. It just filters in the currently received breeze entity.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('appFilter', []).filter('breezeFilter', function () {

    function contains(searchString, searchTerm) {
        if (!searchString) return false;
        return searchString.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) != -1;
    }

    function getKeys(entity) {
        var names = [];
        var properties = entity.entityAspect.extraMetadata.properties;
        for (var property in properties) { names.push(property); }
        return names;
    }

    function search(entity, searchTerm) {
        var found = false;
        if ("entityAspect" in entity) {
            var keys = getKeys(entity);
            for (var i = 0; i < keys.length && !found; i++) {
                if (keys[i].slice(-2) !== "Id") {
                    var obj = entity[keys[i]];

                    switch (typeof obj) {
                        case 'object':
                            if (obj && !('navigationProperty' in obj)) {
                                found = search(obj, searchTerm);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'number':
                        case 'string':
                            found = contains(obj, searchTerm);
                            break;
                        case 'boolean':
                        default:
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

    return function (breezeEntities, expression) {
        if (!expression || expression.length < 2) return breezeEntities;
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(breezeEntities, function (entity) {
            if (search(entity, expression)) {
                filtered.push(entity);
            }
        });
        return filtered;
    }
});
})();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: nice work - struggling to get it to work. What is entity.entityAspect.extraMetadata.properties i dont seem to have a "extraMetadata" object on this.

Comment: @PiotrStulinski hm, that was a long time ago ;) you have to find the property which holds all the keys to the properties of your entity. what version do you use?

Comment: [breeze docs](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/EntityAspect.html#property_extraMetadata)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and I solved by using query projections in breeze, i.e. the "select" clause. It returns pure JavaScript object as opposed to the "wrapped" breeze entities.

Comment: Breeze 1.4.6 just released also has a "noTracking" option that you could use.