# Dynamic select element filtering in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I am using an **ng-repeat** to iterate over objects for displaying in Angular and each of these objects contains a select element containing a property of the object.

I want to filter options based off the selected value for each of the objects' other properties (whew, this is harder to explain than I thought) but the problem is that these are Breeze entities and if I use the traditional method Angular provides the stack throws an overflow exception due to the cyclic nature of Breeze entities.

I have found a good example by Ward on how to create a more static function to handle the filtering, but I am trying to make it more dynamic and am struggling -

In the view I have a list of available fighters, which should be filtered by a fights' weight class, so for each fight in the ng-repeat's fights there is a weight class selector, and two fighter selectors -

**Attempt 1 -**

```
<select
    ng-model="fight.firstFighter"
    ng-options="f.fullName for f in fighters | filter: fighterFilter">
</select>

<select
    ng-model="fight.weightClass"
    ng-options="w.fullName for w in weightClasses">
</select>

$scope.fighterFilter = function (fighter) {
    var fight = ???;
    return fight.weightClass ?
        -1 != fighter.weightClass === fight.weightClass :
        true;
};
```

I have tried sending nothing as shown, but the problem is it only sends the fighter's value as it iterates through each available fighter, so I can't get the value of the fight.weightClass.

Any idea of how to get the context of fight and the fighter I am iterating over?  Or a better approach to filtering this way?

**Fighters Structure**

1. Fighter

   - Id
   - Name
   - WeightClassId
   - WeightClass (navigation property)
2. Fight

   - FirstFighter
   - SecondFighter
   - WeightClassId
   - WeightClass (navigation property)
3. WeightClass

   - Id
   - Weight
   - Description
   - FullName

**Edit**

I have been able to filter results for s single fight without a problem, the problem is how to dynamically handle this on a per fight basis in the same view under the ng-repeat directive.  I cannot get the context of 'fight' and 'fighter' to compare whether the 'weight class' value of both entities match.

Comment: Can you post the data structure of `fighters` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter can take a `expression` as an `Object` in the format of `{fieldName:value}`.

You can use `| filter: {WeightClassId:fight.WeightClass.Id}` to achieve what you want.

```
<li ng-repeat="fight in fights">
    <h4>{{ fight.number }}</h4>

    Weight Class:
    <select ng-model="fight.WeightClass" ng-options="w.Name for w in weightClasses"></select>{{ fight.WeightClass.Name }}

    <br/>First Fighter
    <select ng-model="fight.FirstFighterId" ng-options="f.Name for f in fighters | filter: {WeightClassId:fight.WeightClass.Id}"></select><span>{{ fight.FirstFighter.Name }}</span>

    <br/>Second Fighter
    <select ng-model="fight.SecondFighterId" ng-options="f.Name for f in fighters| filter: {WeightClassId:fight.WeightClass.Id}"></select><span>{{ fight.SecondFighter.Name }}</span>
</li>
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bRGyC/)**</kbd>

Comment: This wouldn't work dynamically though, this is assuming that there is only one fight on each page, where in fact there are multiple, which is why I am using an ng-repeat.  Correct?

Comment: So in my attempt 1 when I statically set the fihgt.weightClass I could easily get it working, as I mentioned, the problem is that I can't get the value of fight no matter what I am doing.  I am trying to see if somehow the scope is changing based off which fighter select list is being populated based on your answer, but I don't see fight ever being populated dynamically.

Comment: Can you post an updated version of my fiddle with your code? It is really hard to just guess your code.

Comment: I have added the basic structure to this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Wd583/2/ - but the problem is a little more in-depth than the fiddle shows obviously.

Comment: Cool, this led me to the answer with a little massaging.  Thanks.  The ID's were just for the demo because I didn't feel like writing custom getters and setters also, if you remove all the 'IDs' in the mark-up the answer is 100% correct and should help any future visitors find the final answer.  Thanks again.